# Do complex sentences omit verbs in dependent clauses?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, syntactic-analysis, word-order, complex-sentences

1.An event came before another event.
2.The earlier event did not happen before the later one.
3.Something had happened before something else.
4.It had not come before the subject.
5.One event happened earlier than the other.

I need to know are these complex sentences with omission of verbs on italic sentences like the below?
1.An event came before another event came.
2.The earlier event did not happen before the later one happened/did not happened.
3.Something had happened before something else happened/had happened.
4.It had not come before the subject comes/had not come.
5.One event happened earlier than the other happened.

Please correct my question if any wrong found, and feel free to answer. Thank you.

Comment: By your logic, ***2 is bigger than 1*** would be a "complex sentence" on the grounds that there's an "omitted verb" *(...than 1 **is**)*. I don't think so.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: No, the question is about the use of _before_. All the examples have _before_ used as a subordinating conjunction introducing an intransitive temporal clause, and also used as a preposition with the subject NP of the temporal clause serving as the object of the preposition. The reasonable question that arises is whether these synonymous constructions are related. Here they clearly are. But _bigger than_ isn't a preposition and can't be expected to behave like one, or like a conjunction, for that matter. And not all prepositions can behave like conjunctions; and vice versa.

Comment: What I mentioned all are complex sentences right?

Comment: No is the simple answer. None of the "before" or "earlier" expressions are clauses; the ones headed by "before" are preposition phrases, and those headed by "earlier" are adverb phrases. They are all functioning as temporal adjuncts. However, the second group of examples do contain dependent clauses: in 1-3 as complement of the PP "before" and in 5. of the preposition "than". (I've ignored 4 since it is ungrammatical).

Comment: @John Lawler: 2 of the 10 examples feature ***earlier than*** rather than a one-word conjunction. I will of course bow to your knowledge of such matters, but it seems to me that in terms of *semantic structure*, statements like ***2 is bigger than 1*** and ***Spring comes before summer*** (or ***2 comes after 1***, come to that) are much the same, so I find it difficult to see how one could be a complex sentence, but not the other one.

Comment: @BillJ You are saying the first group of sentences are not complex sentences they are just preposition phrases and the second group of sentences are complex sentences right?

Comment: "Earlier than" is not a constituent. "Earlier than the other happened" is an adverb phrase with "earlier" as head and the PP "than the other happened" as its complement. The comparative clause "the other happened" is then complement of "than".

Comment: @nanu1 Yes, that is what I am saying.

Comment: @BillJ Actually in the second group of sentences I have only included those verb forms, if we omitted those then we'll get the first group of sentences, then how could you say that the first group of sentences are not complex sentences they are just preposition phrases and the second group of sentences are complex sentences?

Comment: @nanu1 Unlike in the second group, none of the examples in the first contains a dependent clause and hence cannot be complex. I don't take the "before" and "earlier" expressions in the first group to be verbless clauses.

Comment: @BillJ Suppose take an example 'you must work harder than I'. Does this complex sentence?

Comment: @BillJ Reply...

Comment: Sorry, I missed the last sentence. Comparatives work differently, though one can still argue for clause union of one shape or another, depending on what syntactic faith one follows. Not all follow the same tenets and restrictions as @BillJ.

Comment: @ FumbleFingers "Spring comes before summer" is same as "Spring comes before summer comes" and "2 comes after 1" is same as "2 comes after 1 comes",and "you must work harder than I" is same as "you must work harder than I work", if these are same then definitely there is omission of verbs in subordinate clauses in complex sentences right?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reply....